# how to prevent user from clicking button twice on server side in jqx

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$('#save').on('click',function(){
  $('#form').jqxValidator('validate');
});
```

How can I prevent user from click button twice on server side?

Answer (score 1):

Preventing users from submitting forms twice becomes very easy with that module [hide_submit](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit).

Take a look at the issues as many features patched but not yet in the master branch of that module.

It may guides to achieve the same thing for (non submit buttons).